# Cannot count the round with socket in C

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to send hint to 2 clients for two rounds, the hint of each round is different. So I write a simple client and server code.

Here is the server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    //strlen
#include <stdlib.h>    //strlen
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include <unistd.h>    //write
#include <pthread.h> //for threading , link with lpthread
#define N 2 // player numbers
#define CardUpperLimit 10;

// Game setting 
int n = 1000; 
int flag_phase1 = 1;
pthread_t sniffer_thread[N];
char message[256] , client_message[2000];
int PHASE=0; 
int player_index=0;

void *test(void *);
void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    // Socket setting
    int i,j;
    int socket_desc , client_sock , c , *new_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;
    int whoesTurn;

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Bind done");

    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 3);
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    /* Prepare section.. */
    while( (client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) )
    {
        puts("Connection accepted");
        new_sock = malloc(1);
        *new_sock = client_sock;

        if( pthread_create( &sniffer_thread[player_index] , NULL ,  test , (void*) new_sock) < 0)
        {
            perror("could not create thread");
            return 1;
        }

        player_index+=1;

        //  break if all players entry..
        if ( player_index== N ) break;
    }
        printf("All players are in the game!\n");

        /* Phase 1 ... */
        PHASE=1;
        for ( whoesTurn = 0; whoesTurn < N; whoesTurn++)
        {
            /* Communication! */
            bzero(client_message, 256);
            n=whoesTurn+1;
            while(flag_phase1); // busy waiting until this thread function finish..
            flag_phase1=1;
            printf("Finish Communication!!\n");

        }
        n=0;  // reset checking index
        printf("First Phase done..\n");

        /* Phase 2 .. */
        PHASE+=1;
        for (whoesTurn=0;whoesTurn < N; whoesTurn++)
        {
            /* Communication Part! */
            bzero(client_message, 256);
            n=whoesTurn+1;
            while(flag_phase1) {usleep(100);}  // busy waiting until this thread function finish..
            flag_phase1=1;
            printf("Finish Communication!!\n");

        }
        n=0;

        PHASE=0;
        while(1) 
            sleep(1);

    if (client_sock < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

void * test(void *socket_desc)
{
    int i, j;
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
    int read_size;
    int player_index_handler = player_index;

    while(1)
    {
        /* Communication */
        if(n==player_index_handler)
        {
            printf("I am player:%d\n", player_index_handler); 
            if (PHASE==1)
                *message = '1';
            else if (PHASE==2)
                *message = '2';
            write(sock, message, strlen(message));
            printf("[%d],Phase msg sent:%d\n", player_index_handler,atoi(message));

            read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 2000 , 0);
            printf("the client_message is:%s, from player %d\n", client_message, player_index_handler);
            bzero(message,256);

            // Finish works..
            flag_phase1=0;
        }

    }
}
```

And here is my client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n, k;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[256];
    portno = 8888;
    /* Create Socket */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    /* Catch Server IP */
    server = gethostbyname("localhost");
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");

    while(1)
    {

        int read_size =recv(sockfd , buffer , 256 , 0);
        if (read_size>0) 
        {
            // show hint in client..
            printf("%s\n", buffer);
            if (atoi(buffer)==1) 
                printf("FIRST HINT\n");
            else if (atoi(buffer)==2)
                printf("SECOND HINT\n");

            bzero(buffer,256);
            // Enter something..
            printf("Please enter the message: ");
            bzero(buffer,256);
            fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
            n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
            // bzero(buffer,256);
            if (n < 0)  error("ERROR writing to socket");
        }
        else ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem I met is that the "please enter the message" hint shows too many times so that the output shows more than I expect.
How can I make this hint message show when all the client finish input string?

Comment: You have *undefined behavior* in the server, you only allocate space for a single byte and not `sizeof(*new_sock)`. You also have a memory leak as you don't free the memory you allocate.

Comment: Thanks, that is a problem. The problem I met is that the printf hint for client to type shows too many times. Since the condition in the client side for showing the hint is recv(sockfd , buffer , 256 , 0) > 0, and everytime I clean up the message buffer in the thread function, I suppose the hint should only show one time ?

Comment: Try to make a small program and get the input inside of while(1){ /* use printf and scanf here */} and you will see where the actually problem is.

Comment: By the way, always think before you deal with user input, if you need while or a do{}while()

Comment: Probably OT, but the `int c` in the server's `main()` should be `socklen_t c`.

Comment: Also do not expect `recv()` to necessarily return as much bytes as it was told to. One `send()` does not need to match one `recv()`, but up to as many `recv()`'s as `send()` sent bytes.

Comment: neither set of posted code cleanly compiles,  reasons vary from unused variables to unused parameters to missing header files' to numerous implicit conversions between signed/unsigned and different lengths of numeric variables to an 'else;`  as a side note: the strlib.h supplies malloc(), free(), exit(), and atoi() not strlen()

Comment: the `bcopy()` and `bcopy()` requires the header file `strings.h` (note the plural in strings.h)

Comment: for readability and understandability and for ease of documentation with tools like `doxygen` please follow the axiom: only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.

Comment: in the client code, right after calling `listen()`, why have this line twice: `c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);`

Comment: regarding these two line: `new_sock = malloc(1);
        *new_sock = client_sock;`,  client_sock is a number that is a socket number.  It can stand on its' own or be copied   However, it is an integer (either 4 or 8 bytes on most systems, not a single byte) so the code should be: `new_sock = malloc(sizeof( client_sock); if( NULL == new_sock ) { perror( "malloc failed"); cleanup and call exit() }
        *new_sock = client_sock;`  otherwise, writing past the end of allocated memory, which is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: in general, the common programming practice is for `all caps` to be only used for `enum` and `#define` values

Comment: since the function `error()` is defined/declared, strongly suggest consistently calling it rather than sometimes calling `perror()` followed by `return 1`

Comment: there are some 'magic' numbers in the code, like 256 and 2000 and 1000.  'magic' numbers make the code more difficult to understand, debug, mantain.  Suggest #define'ing the numbers with meaningful names, the using those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: in general, it is a bad idea to have variables in the file global space when they are only access in a single function.   For instance suggest moving `message[]` to a 'static' inside the `test()` function

Comment: the function: `fgets()` properly handles a input buffer, so it will not overflow the buffer, there fore, these lines: `            bzero(buffer,256);
            fgets(buffer,255,stdin);` could easily be shortened to only: `fgets( buffer, sizeof( buffer ), stdin )'`

Comment: for readability by us humans, please separate code blocks( if, else, do...while, while, for, switch, case, default) by a blank line

Comment: regarding these lines: `            bzero(buffer,256);
            // Enter something..
            printf("Please enter the message: ");
            bzero(buffer,256);`, why is the call to `bzero()` performed twice?  When, infact, neither of those calls are necessary

Comment: the communication loops in the client and server code do not have any way to exit, so (in the current scenario) they will continue to loop, passing 1 then 2 then forever 0

Comment: Please indent consistently, then, amongst other things it would have been obvious that the server gets into the communication loop and never exits. and the code block beginning with: `if (client_sock < 0)` is never executed.  There are other `control flow` problems in the posted code, but that is the main one.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of the server is undefined for several reasons, foremost:

- you only allocate space for a single byte and not `sizeof(*new_sock)`.
                  – Some programmer dude
- There are unsequenced accesses to `player_index` from `main` (`player_index+=1;`) and from `test` (`int player_index_handler = player_index;`). Think: You can't predict whether the increment in `main` happens before or after the assignment in `test`.

To rectify those two problems, you could make the following changes:

- Define a global array for the sockets

  ```
  int sockets[N];
  ```

  and in `main` change

  ```
          new_sock = malloc(1);
  ```

  to

  ```
          new_sock = sockets+player_index;
  ```
- In `test` change

  ```
      int player_index_handler = player_index;
  ```

  to

  ```
      int player_index_handler = (int *)socket_desc - sockets + 1;    // 1 to N
  ```

Then you can tackle other problems as the missing `volatile` at `int n = 1000;`.